# How do you use Enzyme to check for changes to a React Hooks component after onClick?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

I am trying to write a simple integration test in my 100% React Hooks (React v16.12) project with Enzyme (v3.10), Jest (v24.0) and TypeScript where if I click a button component in my App container, another component displaying a counter will go up by one. The current value of the counter is stored in the state of the App container (see snippets below).

Basically, I `mount` the App component to render its children, then try to simulate a click on the button with Enzyme and check the props of the counter display component to see if its value has gone up. But nothing happens. Not only does the `onClick` handler not get called but I don't seem to be able to retrieve the `value` prop I pass to the `PaperResource` component. So basically I can't test the counter display changes when I click on the button in my Enzyme integration test! The test asserts that the `value` prop goes from 0 to 1, but this assertion fails without an error per seenter code here. Is this because Enzyme support for Hooks is still not there yet or am I doing something daft here? When I run the app on my browser, everything works as expected.

Here's my integration test

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';
import { mount, ReactWrapper } from 'enzyme';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import MakePaperButton from './components/MakePaperButton';
import PaperResource from './components/PaperResource';

describe('App', () => {
  let wrapper: ReactWrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    act(() => {
      wrapper = mount(<App />);
    });
  });

  describe('when make paper button is clicked', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      act(() => {
        wrapper.find('.make-paper__button').simulate('click');
      });
    });

    it('should increase paper resource', () => {
      expect(wrapper.find('.resources__paper').prop('value')).toEqual(1);
    });
  });
});
```

And here is my React code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.scss';
import MakePaperButton from './components/MakePaperButton';
import PaperResource from './components/PaperResource';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [ resources, setResources ] = useState({
    paper: 0,
  });

  const handleMakePaperButtonClick = () => {
    setResources({
      ...resources,
      paper: resources.paper + 1,
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MakePaperButton onClick={handleMakePaperButtonClick} />
      <div className="resources">
        <PaperResource value={resources.paper} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My components are very simple

```
// PaperResource.tsx
import React from 'react';

export default (props: { value: number }) => (
  <div className="resources__paper">
    <span>Paper: {props.value}</span>
  </div>
);
```

```
// MakePaperButton.tsx
import React from 'react';

export default (props: { onClick: () => void }) => (
  <div className="make-paper__button">
    <button onClick={props.onClick}>Make Paper</button>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: looks legit. do you get an error like "simulate expect 1 node but 0 passed" or is test just failed because value is not incrementing?

Comment: @skyboyer just added that info to the question but it just fails the assertion because the value is not incrementing. There are no errors thrown.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've found so far is wrapping the expect statement in a `setTimeout()`.

```
it('should increase paper resource', () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        expect(wrapper.find('.resources__paper').prop('value')).toEqual(1);
    }, 0);
});
```